# Search git log using a comment

Tags: git, terminal, git-bash, git-log

I check my git logs using `git log --stat` which shows me all the commits and the files that were changed in those commits.

Now there is a commit that was  made a long time ago, I remember a part of the commit message such that  when I do `git log --stat | grep 'message text'` the log shows only the commit messages in which 'message text' exists.

I, however need to see at least the commit id along with the grep results. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `--oneline` :

```
git log --oneline | grep -F 'message text'
```

Otherwise, pipe your result through `less`, and searching using less:

```
git log | less
/message text
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using this to get complete information.

```
git log --all --grep='Your text here'
```

Git Version used:

```
git version 2.9.0.windows.1
```

Example:

```
$ git log --all --grep='Favourite Module modifie'
```

Result:

```
commit 8226dce6f4f5ffd8143b8aefdee3b9b971040aa0 
Author: Surender Singh <sure**@gmail.com> Date: Thu Aug 25 11:29:32 2016 +0530 
view Favourite Module modified
```

Comment: Still can't see the commid ids, it just shows all commit messages containing 'Your text here'

Comment: commit 8226dce6f4f5ffd8143b8aefdee3b9b971040aa0
Above shows commit id for the commit

Answer (score 0):

Use opts for grep to show more context lines. Choose appropriate size of num to see your id.

```
grep -A num -B num
```

Answer (score 0):

This will find *your* comment.

```
git log --grep "search text" --author your_name
```

[Atlassian Documentation for git log](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log) Scroll down to "By Message" for more detials.

As an aside you can use --author twice. I needed to look for a set of check-ins made by two developers. This is my favorite way to look for that needle in git's haystack. --pretty=online does two things, 1) each commit is on one line, and 2) the full commit reference number is displayed. Just using --oneline give the same except the commit reference number is abbreviated.

```
git log --grep "#Bug" --author jones --author smith --pretty=oneline

\dev8.4> git log --grep "#Bug" --author jones --author smith --pretty=oneline
80334597b56add0ad4a3ddd02e7a6514bf01ad1e #Bug -- Further Mods To Code - CC Save
16cc3b4e949e965de9b72eb4583fa8df659528a0 #Bug -- Use new get charge function to load CC.
b207498261b4622ef88cb696365bf9af2f3fc6e1 #Bug -- Reference now editable after CC scan.
56385b7a77e2ec9af3b827f6a9ba93c22f267e51 #Bug -- Reload Entire Page after CC charge.
19e9cb05dabd8cc7c9a80e64187821d562af043c #Bug -- force Guid after save event.
c363ed97fdc2b56d1fcd84ca48eb300dbb120a3d #Bug -- Guid was getting lost in some cases.
```